# Map function not working Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): fieldsList.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying too loop over classnames with the querselector, however it is not letting me do so as it is coming up as fieldList is not a function.

Can someone help please?

```
 const fieldsList = document.getElementsByClassName('AutoCompleteChip');

  fieldsList.map((el)=> {
    console.log('textcontent',el.textContent);

  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
const fieldList = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('.AutoCompleteChip'));
```

Because getElementsByClassName returns an HTML collection, not quite an array

Comment: No no, you must use a map function with an array, so using Array.from() you are making sure you have an array to apply the map

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName()` returns a live [`HTMLcollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which will update as you change elements in it which can lead to unexpected side effects.

Unless you need the live functionality you should use [`document.querySelectorAll('.AutoCompleteChip')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) (note the class indicator '.') which returns a static [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which implements its own `forEach()` method so you don't need to transform it into an array.

```
const fieldsList = document.querySelectorAll('.AutoCompleteChip');

fieldsList.forEach((el)=> {
  console.log('textcontent',el.textContent);
})
```

Also, [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a new array. Unless you need the returned array you should use [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).